# Running an onEdit Script on selected sheets only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am new to coding Scripts but have managed to copy and edit (bodge...) a script that will onEdit, put a  custom timestamp into the cell next to the cell where the edit took place. The script targets x2 onEdit columns (3,6), timestamping the cell offset(-1).

The workbook has developed to include multiple sheets now, most of which this script is not appropriate to run on, but I cannot figure out how to specify which sheets it should run on.

The below is the script I have cobbled together which works across all sheets, which I would now like to restrict to specific sheets only.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var colsToWatch = [3,6],
    offset = [-1,-1],
    ind = colsToWatch.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
if (ind === -1 || e.range.rowStart === 1) return;
e.range.offset(0, offset[ind])
.setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd MMM yyyy     HH:mm.ss"))
}
```

Please can someone help me by providing the code to run the scripts on specific sheets only. I would also be grateful for any suggestions of a simpler script to achieve the same aim, especially if it eliminates the timestamp being overwritten if the onEdit cell is subsequently edited after the initial edit.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx ) {
    //Whatever code you put here will only run on Sheet1 or Sheet2
  }
}
```

This works for me (on on Sheet1 and Sheet2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx ) {
    let rg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,9);
    if(rg.isBlank()) {
      rg.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

[JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thank you @Cooper - it works and it's much appreciated!

If anyone does have a way to simplify and/or prevent follow-on timestamp updates after the initial timestamp, I would be grateful.

Comment: Just make sure that the timestamp cell does not contain a timestamp before putting a timestamp in it.

Comment: Apologies - I must have just been testing row 1 which for some reason does not cause a timestamp. The code you suggested @Cooper has not worked, it still timestamps on multiple sheets, other than those specified.

Comment: I tested it and it works for me so you must have a problem in your implementation.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide some suggestions as to how I might be implementing it incorrectly, as I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Learning how to debug your own code is crucial don't give up.

Comment: Use of Logger.log() is helpful and check executions for errors often.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. I appear to implemented it correctly as I now get a little post-it like note appear to say "entry"; however no timestamp and I receive the message on all sheets.

Comment: e.source.toast() is a spreadsheet command that I use for debugging purposes just to let me know that the script is running and it runs on all sheets because onEdit trigger is triggered from any edit in the spreadsheet and e.source.toast('entry') is not inside of the if statement so it fires on all sheets.

Comment: The code I wrote also requires that the cell I'm writing the timestamp to must be blank.

Comment: The code that I provided works.  So when you implement it correctly then your code will work.

Comment: It would appear that Sheet 1&2 have long since been deleted. I have renamed all tabs, so it's difficult to know which sheet was which number originally. Is there a way to adapt your code above (which I can make work now, thank you) to use sheet name, not number?

Comment: Being new to code does not relieve you from the responsibility to write and debug your own code.  Now is a good time to start.  I left you with a link to a good Javascript reference and I assume you can find the documentation to google apps script.  I answered your initial question.  If you wish to check off the question that would be great but whether you do or not I'm done here.

Comment: It's taken me a while to circle round to this problem, but I wanted to thank you for your time back then and for not handing me the answer on a platter; much more satisfying to have solved the problem myself – albeit with a rather large push in the right direction from yourself. Many thanks Cooper